# How to get AWS ALB to pass health check

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, socket.io

I am running a socket.io server on AWS ALB. I am not running NGINX. I am able to connect to my server via TCP, however the health check is failing. How can I setup a health check for an ALB non-nginx socket.io server?

Can I just put a file in /health/healthcheck.html? Since I am not running Nginx how can I serve and HTML file? Is there a file created by socket.io library that I can point the health check to?

Answer (score 0):

Default health check is the port on which each target receives traffic from the load balancer, but you can specify a different port in the Health check advanced settings.

[image]

Comment: Which I have changed to HTTP 8888 Path /health   I am not sure what to put in /health? Html file? But no nginx running so how will html file be served?

Comment: just / is enough, you don't need any HTML file. I don't know what socket.io does. I hope its HTTP app because ALB support only HTTP/HTTPS protocols

Comment: No AWS ELB only supports HTTP/HTTPS. AWS ALB support TCP socket.io and websocket apps.